# how to remove string from the end of foreach loop

Tags: php

can I remove the `OR` from the end of `foreach` loop

```
if (isset($_POST['size'])) {
                    $where .= ' AND ';
                    $s = $_POST['size'];
                    $end = count($s);

                    foreach ($s as $ss) {
                        $where .= 'pSize=' . $ss;
                        $where .= ' OR ';
                    }

                } else {
                    $s = '';
                }
```

Comment: rtrim() or substr() are the usual ways

Comment: can you show me how to use the function in my case

Comment: Read the docs. There are good examples. You can apply those examples to your problem. Or at least try and then come back here.

Comment: What is your idea about if ($end > $end) ?  About your question you can use while() or for() instead foreach()

Comment: it was testing code cleaned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to avoid that issue is create an array and implode.

```
if (isset($_POST['size'])) {
    $where .= ' AND (';
    $s = $_POST['size'];
    $end = count($s);
    //echo $end;
    $aWhere = [];
    foreach ($s as $ss) {
        $aWhere[] =  'pSize=' . $ss;
    }
    $where .= implode(' OR ', $aWhere) . ')';
} else {
    $s = '';
}
```

Maybe you need parentheses on the Where, I did it for you.

Take care with SQL injection, use prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

with your condition, i think you use `IN` for easy.

```
if (isset($_POST['size'])) {
    $size = $_POST['size'];
    if($size){
         $where .= ' AND `pSize` IN ('.implode(",", $size).')';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this will also work in your case:

```
if (isset($_POST['size'])) {
                    $where .= ' AND ';
                    $s = $_POST['size'];
                    $end = count($s);

                    for($i=0;$i<count($s);$i++) {
                        $where .= 'pSize=' . $s[$i];
                        if($i != count($s)-1){
                        $where .= ' OR ';
                       }
                    }

                } else {
                    $s = '';
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can go for many ways 
 way 1:
 you can go for for loop instead of foreach()

```
$a=sizeof($s);
$x=$a-1;
for($i=0;$i<$a;$i++){
if($i==$x){ $where .= 'pSize=' . $ss;
                       }
else{                   $where .= 'pSize=' . $ss;
                        $where .= ' OR ';
}
}
```

way2 : use rtrim()

```
 foreach ($s as $ss) {
                        $where .= 'pSize=' . $ss;
                        $where .= ' OR ';
                    }
$where=rtrim($where,' OR ');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. You can even use a for loop. If you'd prefer a foreach loop, you can create an iterator variable to mimic a for loop as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['size'])) {
                    $where .= ' AND ';
                    $s = $_POST['size'];
                    $end = count($s);

                    $i = 0;
                    foreach ($s as $ss) {
                        $where .= 'pSize=' . $ss;
                        if (++$i != $end) 
                            $where .= ' OR ';
                    }
} else {
     $s = '';
}
```